# Scrollbar is hidden behind the headers

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In recyclerview the scrollbar is hidden behind the headers. I searched a lot and found that others have the same problem but could not find any solution, Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Can you please post your layout for reference, otherwise the answers will all be guessing. You need to clarify your question more.

Comment: it is clear, when you are scrolling the recyclerview everything is fine util it reaches an sticky header, the scrollbar goes below it and disappeared util it passed the header

Comment: Yeah, I still don't quite understand the problem or the question. What Stick Header library are you using. What are the layout settings? More details are needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could not find any right solution but I did a trick, set padding for your sticky header and fill the rest with transparent color, the scrollbar will be visible over the sticky.